# Python - can't convert value from sympy.core.add.Add class to float

Tags: python, string, list, int, sympy

Here's my problem (illustraded with an applicable example):

```
... some code 
### x=0.5*t*(copysign(1, t - 0.5) + 1) + 0.1  
### x=string value
X= Matrix(len(x),1,x)
>>>print X[0]
0.5*t*(copysign(1, t - 0.5) + 1) + 0.1
>>>print type(X[0])
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>

t1=linspace(0,1,2) 

REF=[]

for i in range(len(t1)):
    REF.append(M_ref[0].subs(t,t1[i]))
>>>print REF
0.100000000000000, 0.5*copysign(1, 0.5) + 0.6
```

So `REF[0]` is from the 'sympy.core.numbers.Float' class, but `REF[1]` is from the 'sympy.core.add.Add' class (as are the rest of list values when I expand the `linspace`). Therefore I can't use them in the rest of my code. I tried to use `evalf` but that didn't solve the problem.

I need the values in the REF list to be all floats (or integers).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html, it is just an example (when you use copysign(1,x) it's the same as sign(x))

Comment: I don't see how that can be the copysign from the standard library math, as that one doesn't support being unevaluated or symbolic arguments.

Comment: I get the x value from an interface entry (string), but like you say, I also thought there was a problem with the copysign, although I don't know how to solve it, because I have to get it from my interface in the "copysign(1, x*t)" form and substitute t afterwards with a value

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what is happening.

You are converting your input from strings. SymPy doesn't have a function called copysign, and `sympify` doesn't use the `math` library, so it just creates `Function('copysign')`, which is an unevaluated object. If you want to evaluate it as the `math` `copysign` from the get-go, you can add `{'copysign': math.copysign}` as a second argument when you call sympify, like `sympify('copysign(1, 2)', {'copysign': math.copysign})`. If you want a symbolic version, you will need to create one, as it doesn't exist in SymPy yet. Something like

```
class copysign(Function):
    nargs = 2
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, x, y):
        if x.is_number and y.is_number:
            return math.copysign(x, y)
```

That will work symbolically, but as soon as both arguments are numeric, it will evaluate using the `math` copysign.

```
>>> x, y = symbols('x y')
>>> copysign(x, y)
copysign(x, y)
>>> copysign(1, -2)
-1.0
```

Really, a better way to do it would be to reimplement the copysign logic symbolically, so that it always returns a SymPy type, but I'll leave that to you as an exercise. You can look at how [`sign`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/functions/elementary/complexes.py#L198) is implemented in SymPy to get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response, although this still doesn't seem to solve my problem. It only seems to evaluate the function the first time, for the second value it returns (for example in my project) `".00025*copysign(1, -0.49) + 0.1"`

Comment: Which variant are you using?